# MongoDB update query not working

Tags: mongodb, mongojs

I am running the below query and It does not work. When I run the query part in mongo UI, it returns me expected result. I am using UMongo. But it does not update the document as expected.

```
db.system.js.save ({    
_id:"script_1",
value: function() {

    print("in function>>");             

    db.data.find({"$and": 
        [{"title":{$regex : '.*Green Red.*', $options : 's'}},
         {"editor.key": {"$in": ["74014","45339"]}}, {"types" : {"$in": ["Notes"]}}]}).forEach(
          function(docMatch){
                  print("Matching document found");
                      db.data.update(docMatch, 
                              {$set:{"editor.key": "05335","editor.value": "editor1", 
                          "editor.email": "editor1@gmail.com"}
                    }, false, true);
      }
    );

    db.data.reIndex();
    }
 });

 db.eval("script_1()");
```

I do see "Matching document found" in the mongo logs but does not update. Shows below message too in the logs.

```
     Thu Sep 19 11:03:43 [conn1279] warning: ClientCursor::yield can't unlock b/c of recursive lock ns
```

Thanks for you help !

Comment: whatever generated this code is terribly broken!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what the problem is without having your data and being able to run your query. However, there are lots of issues with this code:

- Why save this as a script and then call db.eval() rather than running your update directly?
- Why do you need to reindex?
- You do not need the $and operator in your query.
- You do not need separate calls to find and update; in fact, one call to update with the multiupdate flag set to true should suffice.
- The $in is unnecessary in {"$in": ["Notes"]}.
- Using {$regex: '.*Green Red.*'} could potentially be slow. The $regex operator cannot use an index in this case because an index can only be used to match a prefix. See the last paragraph here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/regex/.

If this is code generated by UMongo, I recommend moving away from UMongo and working with the officially supported mongo shell.

In order to fix your call to update, try running something like this in the mongo shell:

```
db.data.update(
  {
    "title": {$regex : '.*Green Red.*', $options : 's'},
    "editor.key": {"$in": ["74014","45339"]},
    "types" : "Notes"
  },
  {
    $set: {
            "editor.key": "05335",
            "editor.value": "editor1",
            "editor.email": "editor1@gmail.com"
          }
  },
  false,
  true
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for checking it ... I used  {"types" : {"$in": ["Notes"]} because types is an array. Did not know I can use it without $in. Thanks again for all the suggestions. I am sure it will work now. I will let you know if otherwise.